# Possible Qt Bug. Size of layout does not seem consistent. Would like opinions on it

Tags: java, qt, qt-jambi

First of all, I'm developing an application with QtJambi. When I was using QStackedWidget I ran into this problem and could not find a suitable solution. So what I did was try to isolate the problem, which I did in the following code:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        QApplication.initialize(args);

        QWidget main = new QWidget();
        QVBoxLayout vbox = new QVBoxLayout();
        QPushButton bot = new QPushButton("a");
        vbox.addWidget(bot);

        main.setSizePolicy(Policy.Maximum, Policy.Maximum);
        vbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        vbox.setStretchFactor(bot, 1); //remove this line to have a totally different size

        main.setLayout(vbox);

        main.show();


        QApplication.exec();
    }
}
```

So I think I might have run into a bug (I could be wrong of course, I tried both versions qtjambi 4.7.1 and 4.7.0, compiling for ubuntu 12.10) and would like a confirmation on it.

On the line of code I pointed out, try removing it andthe widget changes size unexpectedly, maybe it is intended? https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#adjustSize says minimum height is 100, but it seems not to be like that, either I use expanding policy or not.

Comment: "I ran into this problem" It would help a gigaton if you said exactly what problem you ran into.

Comment: "I ran into this problem" By that I meant that the size of the widget is not consistent as I mentioned here: "On the line of code I pointed out, try removing it and the widget changes size unexpectedly"
When that single line is added the widget gets bigger, with lots of unused space. While when that line is out, all extra space is gone and the widget becomes really small.